# No storage class may be specified (Objective-c ) error

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I keep getting

```
error: no type or storage class may be specified here before 'interface'
```

Here's the image:

[image]

and the code:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Utilities : NSObject {

}

+ (NSString *)getDocumentsDirectory;
+ (void)showActivityIndicator;
+ (void)hideActivityIndicator;
+ (void)setUser:(NSString *)userName withPassword:(NSString *)password;
+ (NSString *)getUserName;
+ (NSString *)getPassword;
+ (long long)generateTicketNumber;
+ (BOOL)reachable;
+ (NSString *)printerAddress;
+ (NSInteger)port;
+ (void)setAddress:(NSString*)newAddress andPort:(NSInteger)newPort;
+ (void)showDataActivity;

@end


@interface CustomUITextField:UITextField{
    NSInteger rowNumber;
}

@property (nonatomic) NSInteger rowNumber;

@end
```

I reduced the .m file to just simple:

```
#import "Utilities.h"

@implementation Utilities

@end
```

I still get the error. (Ofcourse I get warnings for not implementing methods).

I have been trying to figure out what's wrong for past 2-3 hours. Please help. Thanks.

**UPDATE:**I split up the two classes and all of a sudden, I am gettting "property declaration not found ...." error in a totally different class.

Here's my DataCenter.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@interface DataCenter : NSObject {
    BOOL updating;
    NSDictionary *dataDictionary;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDictionary *dataDictionary;

+ (DataCenter *)sharedInstance;
- (void)update;
- (NSArray *)getSTData;
- (BOOL)saveSTData;
- (NSArray *)getLookUpsData;
- (NSDate *)lastUpdated;

- (NSArray *)pendingData;
- (void)registerNewTicket:(NSDictionary *)ticketInfo;
- (void)savePendingData:(NSArray *)data;

@end
```

And I am getting "Property declaration not in implementation or interface context"

Comment: Is this the only place where you import Utilities.h? If not, check the other places where you import this also.

Comment: I'd split these into two files.

Comment: I vote with Firoze — what you have is valid ObjC, and I've just verified that by running it through Xcode. Is it possible your .h is ending up included or imported by a vanilla C or C++ file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The contents of the header file will be compiled wherever you include/import this header. Check to see that you aren't importing Utilities.h in some other file where there is an error before the #import.

Comment: OK, so where else have you imported this header (or is it these headers now) and what other class is giving you an error now?

Comment: The other place now where this is happening is DataCenter.h . Both DataCenter and Utilities are included in alot of other classes.

Comment: It seems correct to me. Please take a look at original question where I put the code for it.

Comment: Also, take a look at the build log, that might help you narrow this down a bit.

Comment: @user635064 let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1169/discussion-between-firoze-lafeer-and-user635064)

Comment: Hey, figured it out. One of the one that imported both of these .h files didn't have @end in the end. Woow. Took me 3+ days to figure this out (and the errors weren't even close to what the actually problem was)....thanks for all your help.